# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when initialising firebase through admin SDK Java

Tags: java, firebase, gradle, netbeans, firebase-admin

I am trying to connect to firestore through the firebase admin SDK. However, when I call:

```
 FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
            .build();
    
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

I get the following exception: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)'`

I only get this exception when running the program through the jar file, it runs fine when compiled through NetBeans. I read online and it seems to be an issue with versions of the firebase admin SDK, but I am not sure which version to use and have tried multiple versions with the same error.

Maybe it is an error with the way I am bundling my dependencies in the jar file?

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'application'


mainClassName = 'QMPAngola.Main'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.9.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-jre'
    }
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "QMPAngola.Main"
    }
    
    from { (configurations.runtime).collect {it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)} } 
   
}
```

This is the full stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)'                         
        at com.google.cloud.firestore.Query$ComparisonFilter.<init>(Query.java:137)                                                                                                                
        at com.google.cloud.firestore.Query.whereEqualTo(Query.java:423)                                                                                                                           
        at com.google.cloud.firestore.Query.whereEqualTo(Query.java:401)                                                                                                                           
        at QMPAngola.FirebaseUI.driverStart(FirebaseUI.java:315)                                                                                                                                   
        at QMPAngola.FirebaseUI.<init>(FirebaseUI.java:51)                                                                                                                                         
        at QMPAngola.Main$1.run(Main.java:36)                                                                                                                                                      
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)                                                                                                          
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)                                                                                                                 
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)                                                                                                                             
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)                                                                                                                             
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)                                                                                                        
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)                                                                       
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)                                                                                                                     
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)                                                                                          
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)                                                                                             
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)                                                                                          
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)                                                                                                      
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)                                                                                                      
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding `com.google.firebase:firebase-admin` is using `guava` as dependency.

From my understanding you override the transitive dependency to guava by

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-jre'
    }
}
```

with a incompatible version.

I'd say you should remove that block or is there any reason why you added it?

Comment: I had added it in as a result of receiving this exception because I read that the exception may be caused by an outdated guava dependency, so I tried to force it to use the latest version. Unfortunately, it didn't help. I tried running it after deleting that block and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to debug, my first assumption would be on the availability of the config, does the `'serviceAccount'` return a value in an expected format?

Second guess would be that I noticed you are using `FirebaseApp` rather than `admin`
it's entirely possible you are using the wrong modules for the wrong credentials.

Lastly, a possible version mismatch in modules, such as FirebaseCore being installed in newer versions, etc.